# Joining two tables in MVC .NET Core

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, join

I have two tables and I want to display them in my view with a SQL join.
My join can be found in the controller:

```
public RechercheController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
  _context = context;
}

public IActionResult Zangen()
{
   var werkzeuge = _context.Werkzeuge
        .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Werkzeuge, dbo.Werkzeugmodelle 
               WHERE dbo.Werkzeuge.Typ=1 
               AND dbo.Werkzeuge.Werkzeugmodell=dbo.Werkzeugmodelle.Id")
        .ToList();

    ViewBag.Werkzeuge = werkzeuge;
    return View();
}
```

The way I try to display them in my view:

```
<tbody>
@{ 
  foreach (Werkzeug werkzeug in ViewBag.Werkzeuge)
  {

     <tr>
        <td>@werkzeug.Id</td>
        <td>@werkzeug.Number</td>
        <td>@werkzeug.Owner</td>
        <td>@werkzeug.Type</td>
        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
           <td>
             <form asp-action="CreateEdit" asp-route-id="@werkzeug.Id">
                   <button type="submit" 
                           class="btn btn-warning">Bearbeiten</button>
             </form>
           </td>
         }
    </tr>
  }
}
</tbody>
```

The for each loop only grabs the data from the table  `Werkzeuge` but not those from the table `Werkzeugmodelle`.

- How can I display the data from table `Werkzeugmodelle`?

Comment: Mmm, possibly a "lost in translation" thing here; you're saying "dbo" but I think you mean "table" - normally you'd arrange your context (EF?) so it *knows* how the tables in the link together, and the client side objects would support the same relationship, so you'd just say e.g. `_context.Werkzeuge.Include(w => w.Werkzeugmodelles)` or you'd just select from the tables e.g. `_context.Werkzeugemodelles.Select(wm => new { wm.name, wm.Werkzeug.Something})` and your ORM sees you using data from other entities at the remote end of some relation and it does the joins for you

Comment: A pattern of `_context.Werkzeuge
                .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Werkzeuge, dbo.Werkzeugmodelle WHERE dbo.Werkzeuge.Typ=1 AND dbo.Werkzeuge.Werkzeugmodell=dbo.Werkzeugmodelle.Id")` shouldn't be necessary - the ORM knows how to do joins so you don't need to do joins (and definitely should be avoiding joining in this pre-1992 year style) for it.. That plus it perhaps doesn't make sense to Raw joined tables into a single context collection, because it won't understand what to do with the extra columns; EF won't analyze the SQL and go "it uses two tables so I'll populate related..

Comment: ..entities" - the Raw sql you put gets written out as a subquery when the database is queried, and the results of it are mapped into just the named entity that was Raw'd. If you were doing multiple tables in a raw approach you'd need to be more involved, rawing each independently.. But it seems unnecessary here. This should just be something like `_context.Werkzeuge.Include(w => w.Werkzeugmodelles).Where(w => w.Typ = 1)`

Comment: dbo is usally a sign for sql server are you sure that thsi is MySQL

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for your answer, when I write `context.Werkzeuge.Include(w => w.Werkzeugmodelles).Where(w => w.Typ = 1)` in my controller, it says that in my "Werkzeug" Model has to be a definition for "Werkzeugmodelle". Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm guessing at the relationships but for two entities that are related, such as one Customer having many Order, it would be typical for the Customer entity to have an `ICollection<Order> Orders` and for an Order to have a single `Customer Customer` property. This lets EF know about the 1:Many aspect of the relationship between the two and allows you to use these relations in a query to bring data together. You might say `context.Orders.Select(o => new { o.OrderDate, o.Customer.Name })` - EF will see you navigating from order to customer and do a join to make sure the data request is satisfied

Comment: Equally you might say `context.Customers.Select(c => new { c.Orders, c.Name })` and again you're using a navigating property in a Select to travel to another part of the linked-up entity graph and EF makes the sql join for you. Most basic joins can be done automatically once EF knows the links between entities, and when you use data from other entities in a Select or Where the wiring up is done behind the scenes. Using Include allows you to tell EF to download data even if you don't directly use it in a Select or Where, because you plan to use it later and need it available in the entity

Comment: If you're getting "doesn't contain a definition for" then it sounds like your entity doesn't have that property; you need to add it as a property like any other - in EF entities, the simple properties represent database table columns (usually) and complex types (like an Order having a Customer property) properties represent relational links to other tables (orders.customerid FK to customers.id PK on the db side)

Comment: @CaiusJard Now it works in my backend but now I have a problem in my view. The for each loop doesn't display the data `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type` and the for each loop is red underlined. My foor each loop looks like this

Comment: `foreach (Werkzeug werkzeug in ViewBag.Werkzeuge)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@werkzeug.Id</td>
                    <td>@werkzeug.Number</td>
                    <td>@werkzeug.Owner</td>
                    <td>@werkzeug.Werkzeugmodell.Name</td>`

Comment: and `ViewBag.Werkzeuge` is definitely some enumerable of Werkzeug, like a `List<Werkzeug>` ? I ask because it used to work before when it was a `List<Werkzeug>` from `context.Werkzeuge...ToList()` but if you've now done e.g. `context.Werkzeuge.Select(w => new { w.Id, w.Number, w.Werkzergmodell.Name}` then the thing in the `viewbag.Werkzeuge` isn't a `Werkzeug`